# Serving socket.io through SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I'd like to implement ssl in all of my projects. One of them is using socket.io.

My code to create the socket:

```
var server = require('http');
var app = server.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.end();
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(8000);
```

I can't bind node.js / socket.io to ssl port cause it's already in use by my webserver (cherokee). Therefore i can't serve the client using https.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind one application to a port. Since your web server is already bound to port 443, you have two choices:

- Run the web server like you are now and proxy the node.js stuff running on port 8000:
  http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_proxy.html
- Run node.js on that port, change the port of the web server and proxy the web server using node.js: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy